# Categorize documents in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, categories

I am switching from Lotus Notes into sharepoint, but I find it hard to access the data that I want easily. I am currently using documents application on sharepoint. The only options it offers are creating or uploading a new file or folder. In my lotus notes I can access files in different ways based on some categorizations such as client, author, date modified and some other categorizations. Moreover I can even categorize them based on data and client at the same time for example. All I need to do is a single click and everything is managed by notes. What are your suggestions?

Comment: Stay with Notes Domino ;)

Comment: I wish I could but, it isn't me who takes the decision.

Answer (score 3):

That's why an "easy" migration so sharepoint never works: Notes is not only a "datastore" but almost every time contains application logic. 
To get the same in sharepoint, you need to export the "metadata" of your application including attachments and evertyhing to a structure that you can import in sharepoint.

Then you need an "application" in sharepoint that has the necessary fields for your metadata and different views in sharepoint.

You need development knowledge on side of Lotus Notes to create your export and development knowledge on SharePoint to create the application there and import the data.

Without someone who knows how it works or one of the "magic migration tools" in the market, you will not succeed.

And this is something that nobody who makes an analysis to migrate to outlook / sharepoint takes into account... 
And this is the reason, why every company trying to migrate that I know still uses Domino in addition to Outlook / Sharepoint and not even one was able to shutdown the domino servers / get rid of Notes- Client...

Comment: I think that all the migration tools fail to achieve the intended results. I have tried a couple of them with best reviews but they don't work properly (transporter suite, quest migrator). Have you used one of these migrations tools ?

Comment: No. Thats why "magic migration tools" was in quotes. None of them are able to "understand" the application logic - at least the one we tried. We are a group of Notes- and Sharepoint- developers that work together in such migrations, and we had some of them the last months. And it has ALWAYS been coding effort...